# Javascript await not happening while streaming to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, stream

Requirement : I am supposed to hit around 100 links given in a file and download it **sequentially**. The response content type is octet stream file (.ts file). I am using "got" library to stream. However I am not able to do the task sequentially even though i am using await function.

I **Do not** want to hit all the links asynchronously and then do Promise.allsettled().
I want to it to be in sequential manner.

however in the output, i am seeing the for loop executing without waiting for previous file to be downloaded and written to file completely.
First all the console.log statements for each file is getting printed and then writing to file is happening until process is not yet exited.
(each file size is around 2 mb)

How do I execute this sequentially ?

```js
const allFileLines = allFileContents.split(/\r?\n/);

async function makeApiCall(){
  for await(const line of allFileLines){
      if (line.startsWith("https")) {
          const fileName = new URL(line).pathname.split('/')[1];
          const downloadPathAndFile = `${download_path}${dirName}/${fileName}`;
          console.log(`Downloading file : ${fileName}`);
          await downloadFileWithGot(line, downloadPathAndFile, getOptions(line))
      }
  }
}

await makeApiCall();


// in a different utility file
export async function downloadFileWithGot(url, outputLocationPath, options) {
    console.log('entered inside fn');
    const pipeResp = await got.stream(url, undefined, options)
    console.log('got pipe resp');
    const writeResp = await pipeResp.pipe(createWriteStream(outputLocationPath));
    console.log('successfully wrote to file');
    return writeResp;
}

/* 

File in which links are present (its a simple txt file) : 

https://example.com/__segment:12345/stream_1/file_0.ts
https://example.com/__segment:12345/stream_1/file_1.ts
.
.



 ------------ output ------------
Downloading file : file_0.ts
entered inside fn
got pipe resp
successfully wrote to file
Downloading file : file_1.ts
entered inside fn
got pipe resp
successfully wrote to file

.
.
.
 */
```

Comment: You can't just add `await` before any function you want. `await` works only on promises

Comment: @KonradLinkowski based in your inputs, i have moved the for loop inside a async function and then making a call, still its not working the expected way.

Comment: The problem is that `pipe` doesn't return a promise